# Show div on click and hide on next click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to show information based on the item that it is clicked on.
I have some jquery code that works, but not when there are multiple div's in a div.

Here, the first part is what I want, the second part doesn't work because there are div's in the main div. hope that makes sense. How do i make it work?

I think it has something to do with :

```
$("#parent2").find("div:eq('" + i + "')").show().siblings().hide();
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5yyrojsq/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to toggle direct descendants, if you just `find('div')` it will find nested too.

So you can do either this:

```
$("#parent2 > div:eq('" + i + "')").show().siblings().hide();
```

or this:

```
$("#parent2").children("div:eq('" + i + "')").show().siblings().hide();
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `children()` instead of `.find()` and [`.index(element)`](https://api.jquery.com/index/#index-element) can be used to get `index` of anchor element to be displayed.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#div1, #div2, #div3, #div4').hide();
    $('#div5, #div6, #div7, #div8').hide();

    $(".firstpart a").click(function() {
        $("#parent1").children("div").eq($(".firstpart a").index(this)).show().siblings().hide();
    });
    $(".secondpart a").click(function() {
        $("#parent2").children("div").eq($(".secondpart a").index(this)).show().siblings().hide();
    });
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5yyrojsq/5/)

Additionally, You don't need `.each()` to bind event handler.

Answer (score 2):

https://jsfiddle.net/5yyrojsq/4/ You should try to use declarative JS and use classes instead of ID to match elements.

```
<div class="firstpart">
  <a href="#" data-show="div1" class="btn">show div1</a>
  <a href="#" data-show="div2" class="btn">show div2</a>
  <a href="#" data-show="div3" class="btn">show div3</a>
  <a href="#" data-show="div4" class="btn">show div4</a>
</div>
<div id="parent1">
  <div id="div1" class="child_div">hello1</div>
  <div id="div2" class="child_div">hello2</div>
  <div id="div3" class="child_div">hello3</div>
  <div id="div4" class="child_div">hello4</div>
</div>
```

and the JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.child_div').hide();

  $(".btn").click(
    function () {
      $('.child_div').hide();
        var the_div_id_to_show = $(this).attr("data-show");
      $("#" + the_div_id_to_show).show("slow");
    }
  );

});
```

I have simplified the problem to show the general principle as opposed to the specific answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should try doing a toggle() instead of show/hide and then do that on click, like this:

```
$(this).on('click', function() {
   $("#parent1").find("div:eq('" + i + "')").toggle().siblings();
)};
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this ;)

Used a class with div to access them in `eq()`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $parent1 = $("#parent1");
  var $parent2 = $("#parent2");
  $(".firstpart a").each(function(i) {
    $(this).click(function() {
      $('.item:visible', $parent1).hide();
      $parent1.find("div:eq('" + i + "')").show();
    });
  });

  $(".secondpart a").each(function(i) {
    $(this).click(function() {
      $('.item:visible', $parent2).hide();
      $parent2.find("div.item:eq('" + i + "')").show();
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.item {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="firstpart">
  <a href="#">show div1</a>
  <a href="#">show div2</a>
  <a href="#">show div3</a>
  <a href="#">show div4</a>
</div>
<div id="parent1">
  <div id="div1" class="item">hello1</div>
  <div id="div2" class="item">hello2</div>
  <div id="div3" class="item">hello3</div>
  <div id="div4" class="item">hello4</div>
</div>

<br>
<br>
<br>

<div class="secondpart">
  <a href="#">show div5</a>
  <a href="#">show div6</a>
  <a href="#">show div7</a>
  <a href="#">show div8</a>
</div>
<div id="parent2">
  <div id="div5" class="item">
    <div class="row5">hello5</div>
  </div>
  <div id="div6" class="item">
    <div class="row6">hello6</div>
  </div>
  <div id="div7" class="item">
    <div class="row7">hello7</div>
  </div>
  <div id="div8" class="item">
    <div class="row8">hello8</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would change this to make your code more accesible and make use of the anchors href:

```js
// probably want to change this to target a class rather than all anchors
$("a").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // stop default action of anchor
  $($(this).attr('href')).show().siblings().hide(); // show the targetted div and hide it's siblings
});
```

```css
.parent > div {display:none;} /*start divs hidden*/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="firstpart">
  <a href="#div1">show div1</a> <!-- give anchors href of the div they are targeting, maybe a class too -->
  <a href="#div2">show div2</a>
  <a href="#div3">show div3</a>
  <a href="#div4">show div4</a>
</div>
<div id="parent1" class="parent">
  <div id="div1">hello1</div>
  <div id="div2">hello2</div>
  <div id="div3">hello3</div>
  <div id="div4">hello4</div>
</div>

<br><br><br>

<div class="secondpart">
  <a href="#div5">show div5</a>
  <a href="#div6">show div6</a>
  <a href="#div7">show div7</a>
  <a href="#div8">show div8</a>
</div>
<div id="parent2" class="parent">
  <div id="div5"><div class="row5">hello5</div></div>
  <div id="div6"><div class="row6">hello6</div></div>
  <div id="div7"><div class="row7">hello7</div></div>
  <div id="div8"><div class="row8">hello8</div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Updated your same piece of code using `toggle()` instead of `show()` and `hide()`

**HTML**

```
<div class="firstpart">
  <a href="#">show div1</a>
  <a href="#">show div2</a>
  <a href="#">show div3</a>
  <a href="#">show div4</a>
</div>
<div id="parent1">
  <div id="div1">hello1</div>
  <div id="div2">hello2</div>
  <div id="div3">hello3</div>
  <div id="div4">hello4</div>
</div>

<br><br><br>

<div class="secondpart">
  <a href="#">show div5</a>
  <a href="#">show div6</a>
  <a href="#">show div7</a>
  <a href="#">show div8</a>
</div>
<div id="parent2">
  <div id="div5">hello5</div>
  <div id="div6">hello6</div>
  <div id="div7">hello7</div>
  <div id="div8">hello8</div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#div1, #div2, #div3, #div4').toggle();

    $(".firstpart a").each(function(i) {
        $(this).click(function() {
            $("#parent1").find("div:eq('" + i + "')").toggle().siblings();
        });
    });
});
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#div5, #div6, #div7, #div8').toggle();

    $(".secondpart a").each(function(i) {
        $(this).click(function() {
            $("#parent2").find("div:eq('" + i + "')").toggle().siblings();
        });
    });
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shishirmax/hk95z3ad/)

Answer (score 1):

I think this will work for your 'parent2' div:

```
$("#parent2").children("div:eq('" + (i) + "')").show().siblings().hide();
        });
```